# Simplifying Styled Component Media Queries using React.js and Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui, styled-components

I have created three functions for handling media queries in Styled Components.  One is for handling `min-width` media queries, the second for `max-width` and the third for both `min-width` and `max-width` queries.

Here they are:

```
const breakpoints = {
  tablet: 768,
  desktop: 1024,
  widescreen: 1216,
  fullhd: 1408
}

const breakpointsKeys = Object.keys(breakpoints)

const media = Object.keys(breakpoints).reduce((obj, query) => {
  let queryUnit

  if (typeof mediaQueryUnit !== 'undefined') {
    queryUnit = mediaQueryUnit
  } else {
    queryUnit = 'px'
  }
  obj[query] = (...styles) => css`
    @media (min-width: ${breakpoints[query] + queryUnit}) {
      ${css(...styles)}
    }
  `
  return obj
}, {})



const mediaDown = Object.keys(breakpoints).reduce((obj, query) => {
  let queryUnit

  if (typeof mediaQueryUnit !== 'undefined') {
    queryUnit = mediaQueryUnit
  } else {
    queryUnit = 'px'
  }
  obj[query] = (...styles) => css`
    @media (max-width: ${breakpoints[query] - 1 + queryUnit}) {
      ${css(...styles)}
    }
  `
  return obj
}, {})

const mediaOnly = Object.keys(breakpoints).reduce((obj, query, index) => {
  let nextIndex = breakpointsKeys.indexOf(query) + 1
  let nextIndexQuery = breakpointsKeys[nextIndex]
  let maxQuery = breakpoints[nextIndexQuery]

  let queryUnit

  if (typeof mediaQueryUnit !== 'undefined') {
    queryUnit = mediaQueryUnit
  } else {
    queryUnit = 'px'
  }
  obj[query] = (...styles) =>
    maxQuery &&
    css`
      @media (min-width: ${breakpoints[query] +
          queryUnit}) and (max-width: ${maxQuery + queryUnit}) {
        ${css(...styles)}
      }
    `
  return obj
}, {})
```

And this is how I use them in a styled component:

```
const Button = styled.div(
  ({
    tablet,
    tabletDown,
    tabletOnly,
  }) => css`

    ${media.tablet`
      background: blue;
   `}

   ${media.tabletDown`
     background: yellow;
   `}

   ${media.tabletOnly`
     background: green;
   `}
  `
)
```

What I would like to do is to combine these three functions into one function.  I could then use it like this:

```
${media.down.tablet`
  background-color: yellow;
`}
```

Or some similar syntax.  I'm not so worried about the syntax right now as I am with having one function rather than three.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks (in advance) for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to reinvent the wheel rather than just following the existing functionality from Material-UI: https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
      backgroundColor: green[500],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: also your breakpoints are off because 768 should not be a limit but rather it should be a value that happens to fall in the "small" range that exists between 600 and 960 pixels.